# Google Maps Activity showing blank screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to Android and working on an Android app with a Google Maps Activity. I have signed the app with a keystore and generated an API key, that all worked fine. I´ve placed the API key as a string in the app and added the permissions as well as the key to the Android manifest. I´ve checked if the API is activated in the Google dev console, and it is. It all looks fine, I don´t get any errors in the Logcat nor crashes the app - but still, I don´t see any locations in the screen when opening up the Maps activity. I am using a Mac and a Samsung Grand Prime for developing and testing, and I am connected through a regular WiFI.

Here´s the Maps Activity:

```
package de.die_web_agenten.www.batprice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    //private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.batprice.com");

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        //        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }




    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    //@Override
    /*public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }*/
}
```

Here´s the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.die_web_agenten.www.batprice">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="de.die_web_agenten.www.batprice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.die_web_agenten.www.batprice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <!--
            The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
            (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
            Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
            You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
            sign the APK for publishing.
            You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
       -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0"
            android:value="MyAPIkey" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_results"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TrainingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_training"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBarcodeQrExample"
            android:label="@string/title_barcode_class"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here´s the Layout file webview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing here or doing wrong? Any hints and any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Kindly check your layout which you are binding to the Activity. According to your it looks your doing something wrong.

Comment: @dhuma1981 - ok, great, thanks - I added the layout file that the activity is using. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Why you are using WebView? Just google about how to integrate Google Maps to Android and you will get your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code don't make a Google Maps, it is a WebView only.

Comment: ok, thanks so far. I followed the instructions, used the code in the post, and still have a blank screen. Everything works fine, no errors - but still, no location shown. Any more hints?

Comment: Do you have any messages inside the Logcat? it may be help us.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ibrahim - thanks for the hint, that solved my issue. There as a problem with the Google API key, which is now fixed.